# google activity recognition on kitkat 4.4 not working

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat, activity-recognition

I have created an application that recognizes activity using google play services API.
It works fine in devices with android version 2.3 to 4.3 but it doesn't work on 4.4 (kitkat)!
Yesterday I've received the google play services sdk update (revision 14) but the problem persists.
Is there anyone with same problem?
I can't figure it out why it doesn't work. My device is still in 4.3 and I cant test it.
How can I overcome this? Any idea?
Thanks.
Fernando

Comment: Well! nevermind. I have figure it out. Actually it works the device of my colleague were I was testing had the location services deactivated and the activity recognition needs the location services enabled!

Answer (score 2):

I have figure it out myself. Actually it works, the device where I was testing had the location services deactivated and the activity recognition needs the location services enabled.
Just enabled it in the Settings "et voilà"!